# Any way to copy message body from Apple Mail keeping quoted line prefix (">")?

Tags: applescript, mail.app

When I copy the body of messages in Apple Mail and paste to the text editor or web textarea, quoted line prefixs ('>') is alwasy lost. This is annoying behavior.

Is there any way to copy them with keeping quoted line prefixes? 
Such Applescript, Mail extension or App?

** My environment is:  OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) + Apple Mail 7.3 (1878.6)*

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac with Mail 10.3, I can select a message in a viewer window, go to the menu bar and choose View > Message > Raw Source.  In the resulting window I can scroll to find the part of the message I want, and select the text I want to copy.  I just tested this on two messages from my Sent mailbox, one with Rich Text, one without.

Blank quoted lines seem to get an '=20' escape, so you'd want to do a search and replace after pasting.  It might not be too hard to make an AppleScript or Automator thing to help with this.

With an older version of Mail you might find the Raw Source command in a different menu, I seem to remember.

Comment: Thx. This solution works well if body is composed of US-ASCII but not work in other languages such as ja_JP (UTF-8 or ISO-2022-JP charset).